# How is this code running?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

Here is the code first, it comes from 'Ruminations on C++' chapter 10

```
// TestCode.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

class P_Node
{
    friend class Picture;
protected:
    P_Node() : use(1)
    {

    }
    virtual ~P_Node()
    {

    }
private:
    int use;
};

class Picture
{
    friend Picture frame(const Picture&);
public:
    Picture() : p(new P_Node)
    {
        cout << "Constructor\t" << "Picture::Picture()" << "\tcalled" << endl;
        cout << "Picture p count\t" << p->use << endl;
    }
    Picture(const Picture& orig) : p(orig.p)
    {
        cout << "Copy Constructor\t" << "Picture::Picture(const Picture&)" << "\tcalled" << endl;
        cout << "Picture p count\t" << p->use << endl;
        orig.p->use++;
    }
    ~Picture()
    {
        cout << "Destructor\t" << "Picture::~Picture()" << "\tcalled" << endl;
        cout << "Picture p count before decrease\t" << p->use << endl;
        if(--p->use == 0)
        {
            cout << "Picture p count after decrease\t" << p->use << endl;
            cout << "Deleted" << endl;
            delete p;
        }
    }
    Picture& operator=(const Picture& orig)
    {
        cout << "operator=\t" << "Picture& Picture::operator=(const Picture& orig)" << "\tcalled" << endl;
        cout << "Picture p count before decrease\t" << p->use << endl;
        orig.p->use++;
        if(--p->use == 0)
        {
            cout << "Picture p count after decrease\t" << p->use << endl;
            delete p;
        }
        p = orig.p;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Picture(P_Node* p_node) : p(p_node)
    {
        // Why not p_node->use++?
        cout << "Picture::Picture(P_Node* p_node)\tcalled" << endl;
    }
    P_Node *p;
};

class Frame_Pic : public P_Node
{
    friend Picture frame(const Picture&);
private:
    Frame_Pic(const Picture& pic) : p(pic)
    {
        cout << "Frame_Pic::Frame_Pic(const Picture& orig)" << "\tcalled" << endl;
    }
    Picture p;
};

Picture frame(const Picture& pic)
{
    return new Frame_Pic(pic);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Picture my_pic;
    frame(my_pic);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Constructor Picture::Picture()  called
Picture p count 1
Copy Constructor    Picture::Picture(const Picture&)    called
Picture p count 1
Frame_Pic::Frame_Pic(const Picture& orig)   called
Picture::Picture(P_Node* p_node)    called
Destructor  Picture::~Picture() called
Picture p count before decrease 1
Picture p count after decrease  0
Deleted
Destructor  Picture::~Picture() called
Picture p count before decrease 2
Destructor  Picture::~Picture() called
Picture p count before decrease 1
Picture p count after decrease  0
Deleted
```

I have two questions about this code:

1. Why is the copy constructor called before `Frame_Pic`'s Constructor? In my mind, the copy constructor is called because `frame(my_pic)` is returning a `Picture` by value. But that should be called after `Frame_Pic`'s Constructor.
2. In `Picture::Picture(P_Node* p_node)`, why not increase the use count? isn't this creating a new `Picture`?

Thanks for any help.

I'm using VC6 under Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1, Why is the Copy Constructor called before Frame_Pic's Constructor?

Because the `p` member is being copy-constructed in the initialization list of Frame_pic's constructor. The initialization list runs before the constructor's body is entered.

> In my mind, the Copy Constructor is called because frame(my_pic) is returning a Picture by value. But that should be called after Frame_Pic's Constructor.

`frame()` is declared to return a `Picture` instance by value, but it is coded to return a `Frame_pic*` instead.  `Frame_pic` derives from `P_node`, and `Picture` has a constructor that accepts a `P_node*`, and that constructor is accessible to `frame()` so the compiler allows it.

> 2, In Picture::Picture(P_Node* p_node), why not increase the use count? isn't this creating a new Picture?

The use count is on `P_node`, not `Picture`. The `Picture` that `frame()` returns owns the `Frame_pic` that `frame()` creates, whose use count member is already 1 by the `Frame_pic` constructor. That is why that `Picture` constructor does not increment the use count - it is already at the correct value.

The `Frame_pic` contains its own `Picture` that is copy-constructed from another `Picture`, so that `Picture` constructor needs to increment the use count of the original `Picture`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still have a question about the copy constructor: if I wrote Picture `p = frame(my_pic)`, will the copy consrtuctor be called? or if I wrote `Picture p(frame(my_pic))`, will it be called? Seems that the copy constructor is NOT called if I wrote my code like this

Comment: That depends on compiler optimizations. Because the return value of `frame()` is a `Picture` by value, the compiler may decide to default-construct `p`, pass it by a hidden reference into `frame()`, and then use the `=` assignment operator to fill it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
Frame_Pic(const Picture& pic) : p(pic)
{
    cout << "Frame_Pic::Frame_Pic(const Picture& orig)" << "\tcalled" << endl;
}
```

You initializing 'p' using its copy constructor 'p(pic)', hence it gets called in the order you see

Comment: No, the new `Picture` that `frame()` returns is not referencing the original `Picture` directly, so it should not be incrementing the use count. The new `Picture` holds a new `Frame_pic`, who then references the original `Picture`. The `Frame_pic` does increment the use count. The original code is acting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. The copy constructor is invoked *by* Frame_Pic's constructor (it's invoked by the initializer `: p(pic)`). However Frame_Pic's constructor doesn't print until after all initializers have been run.
2. Because the intended use of the constructor is not documented, it's hard to say. It may be a bug, or it may be 'attach semantics' - that  is, it may be considering the case where you take manual control of the `P_Node*`, then later give it back. However attach semantics is unlikely, as there's no corresponding detach mechanism to return the pointer and clear it without decrementing the refcount. So, most likely a bug.

Note that while this sort of manual reference counting can be good as a learning exercise, modern C++ code generally uses smart pointers (eg, `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`, `invasive_ptr`, etc) to automate the process.

Comment: I used BoundsChecker to check the code if there is any memory leak, turns out the original code is correct, and if I increase the number in Picture::Picture(P_Node*), it will cause memory leak